# Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error when calling CreateTableAsync from SQLite-net-pcl on Xamarin Forms - Android

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

After the last visual studio upgrade I'm now getting the error

Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 'index=538968388 out of bounds (limit=591768, nb=2)'

when calling await db.CreateTableAsync(); on Xamarin Forms - Android.

Works fine with UWP.

Comment: MAYBE this will help:  Exit Visual Studio. Delete bin and obj folders of your Android project. This ensures a fully clean Rebuild of your android project.

Comment: Turns out that even though I was getting the error when calling db.CreateTableAsync(), it was Font Awesome problem.  I still don't know what the problem was but when I removed Font Awesome from the page, it went away.

Comment: FYI: Maybe. But if you add Font Awesome back, does the problem start again? If not, then it wasn't Font Awesome. It was the VS update causing something in bin or obj folders to not match the updated version of something. Another action to consider, is Solution Explorer / Manage Nugets. If any Nugets have Updates, apply them.